# Ignore accented letters in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have a javascript as shown below in which Line A prints the following output at console.

```
const megaList = sortedMegaList.reduce((r, e) => {
    let group = e.title[0];  // Line B
    console.log(group);   // Line A
}, {});
```

**o/p at console: (Line A)**

```
B
C
D
E
É
G
H
I
L
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make at Line B so that it ignores accented letters.

Comment: Maybe use a regex pattern to create your array of matched valid characters.

Comment: @ExpressoBeans I am wondering if you can give hint in an answer then that would be great.